# SQL update each column values based on query result with join and group by

Tags: sql

I have an app table with ID and app name,
I want to add a column which contains the number of

table app

```
|ID app | app name |
|A001   | app01    |
|A002   | app02    |
|A003   | app03    |
|A004   | app04    |
|A005   | app05    |
```

and a chart table

```
|ID chart|ID APP|
|C01     |A001  |
|C01     |A002  |
|C02     |A001  |
|C02     |A003  |
|C03     |A004  |
...
```

and i want to add new column to the app table which containts the total number of chart which an app included in. here's the example :

```
|ID app | app name |number of chart they're in|
|A001   | app01    |2                         |
|A002   | app02    |1                         |
|A003   | app03    |2                         |
|A004   | app04    |3                         |
|A005   | app05    |1                         |
```

because app01 is in two chart (C01 and C02), and so on.

i added a new column "number_chart" (number of chart they're in), and i tried this:

```sql
update app
set number_chart = (select count(app.id_app)
                    from app
                          inner join Chart on App.ID_App = Chart.ID_App
                    group by app.id_app);
```

but here's the error that i got :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.

how do i solve this? is there any other way? thanks!

Comment: I removed the tags [[tag:mysql]] and [[tag:sql-server]] for a reason; they are ***completely*** different products. Don't readd conflicting tags, it doesn't help us help you. Just tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0):

According to which database do you use, this query may be different.

But you can use the update statement with **select from query**

```
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
```

Now, for your question, you can use below query:

```sql
update app
set number_chart = tmp.count
from (
  select p.id_app, count(p.id_app)
  from 
    app p inner join chart c on p.id_app = c.id_app
  group by p.id_app
) tmp
where app.id_app = tmp.id_app
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this but it gives this error 'No column name was specified for column 2 of 'tmp'.' am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Maybe need to add an alias name on column `count(p.id_app)`. Which database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update App a 
inner join 
          (  select ID_App,
                    count(id_chart) as 'Nr_of_chart_in'
             from  Chart  
             group by ID_App
          ) as c1 on a.ID_App = c1.ID_App
set a.number_chart = c1.c1.Nr_of_chart_in;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/165

> Results for datas in the demo:
>
> ```
> ID_App    app_name    number_chart
> A001      app01          2
> A002      app02          1
> A003      app03          1
> A004      app04          1
> A005      app05          0
> ```